# How chrome extension will listen when navigated any website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need a listener in my chrome extension that can listen when a web site will navigate then the extension will collect the navigated url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is the **`chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener**, that will fire every time a tab changes URL and loads a new page.

To do this you'll need to follow two simple steps:

1. Add the `tabs` permission to your `manifest.json`, so it will look like this:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,

       "name": "Extension name",
       "description": "Your description...",
       "version": "1",

       "permissions": [
           "<all_urls>",
           "tabs"
       ],

       "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }

   }
   ```
2. Now, in your `background.js` you can add the listener, that will look like this:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID, info, tab) {
       var tabURL = tab.url;
       // here is the url of the tab
       // now you can do whatever you want with it
   });
   ```

---

I strongly suggest you to take a look at the other methods and objects of the `tabs` API, so **you may find helpful the [official documentation for `chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
.**

Comment: How about `chrome.webNavigation` instead? More useful information.

Comment: @Xan just another valuable method, I answered with the one I'm familiar with